# Table layout set to fixed, cell doesn't stretch

Tags: html, css

This problem I'm experiencing is really bugging me. Suppose I have a table with certain width and I set the `table-layout` to `fixed`. Then I set the witdh of every cell except one. According to definition found here: [W3C definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#fixed-table-layout) what should happen is, that the cell should stretch to width which is remaining. This doesn't happen in my case and I'm furious. Here's the [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GoaHi) .

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove `display: block` from the table row, it will take it's default value `display: table-row`.  This will allow the table cells to stretch.

**Example**

```
.uploadedTable tr {
    display: table-row;
}
```

### [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rzjto)